# Jquery Animation seems strange

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-animate

I'm wondering on what happened to my code. This code should animate all the images inside the array. But everytime it will animate strange happen. Hope Someone can help me distingush the problem.

`HTML part.`

```
<div id="container" align="center">
    <div id="slider-wrapper">
        <div id="slider">
            <div class="backgoundImage">
                <div id="images"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`SCRIPT part.`

```
function animate_image(){
         $(document).ready(function(){
            var backgroundImage = new Array(); 
            backgroundImage[0] = "images/image1.jpg";
            backgroundImage[1] = "images/image2.jpg";
            backgroundImage[2] = "images/image3.jpg";
            backgroundImage[3] = "images/image4.jpg";
            backgroundImage[4] = "images/image5.jpg";
            backgroundImage[5] = "images/image6.jpg";
            backgroundImage[6] = "images/image7.jpg";
            $.each(backgroundImage, function(index, value){
                $("#images").append('<div class = "sp"><img src = "' + value + '" /></div>');
                //$('#images img:gt(0)').hide();
                //setInterval(function(){$('#images :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('#images');}, 1000);
            });
        });
     }

     animate_image();
     $('#images img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#images :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('#images');
    }, 1000);
```

Everytime it fades, all images will display then fades again and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no use of `$(document).ready()` inside a function, and to animate all the images you should have a starting point.

Then you are animating using the `setInterval`  which alone is not known to have mercy on your browser even if it is minimized or tab switched.

Use [`requestAnimationframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) for smoother and fluid animations it also helps to control the factors such as your laptop/ phone/tablet going into battery mode and having its performance reduced. Factors such as another tab taking focus. Read More [Here](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/animating_with_requestAnimationFrame.htm)

Also along with the `requestAnimationframe` if you have to stop the animation too so use [`cancelAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/cancelAnimationFrame).

- Start with adding the images to the document and then hide all except the first image.
- Start Animation by calling the `requestAnimationFrame(animationFunction)` .
- Use SetTimeout to queue the animation and call recursively `requestAnimationFrame(animationFunction)` .

See demo below i used FontAwesome Icons for the demo purpose, so change a few things in the following

Replace the class name with the image path

```
var backgroundImage = new Array(
    "fa fa-address-book",
    "fab fa-accessible-icon",
    "fa fa-ambulance",
    "fab fa-amilia",
    "fa fa-anchor",
    "fab fa-android",
    "fab fa-angellist",
  );
```

and change the line

```
$("#images").append('<div class = "sp"><i class = "' + value + '"></i></div>');
```

to

```
$("#images").append('<div class = "sp"><img src= "' + value + '" ></div>');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //background images
  var backgroundImage = new Array(
    "fa fa-address-book",
    "fab fa-accessible-icon",
    "fa fa-ambulance",
    "fab fa-amilia",
    "fa fa-anchor",
    "fab fa-android",
    "fab fa-angellist",
  );

  // store your requestAnimatFrame request ID value
  var requestId;

  //add images to the document
  $.each(backgroundImage, function(index, value) {
    $("#images").append('<div class = "sp"><i class = "' + value + '"></i></div>');
  });

  // hide all but not the first image
  $('#images div.sp').not(':first-child').hide();

  //start animation
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
});


//the animation function
function animate() {
  setTimeout(function() {

    //save the id returned from the function to use it 
    //for canceling or stopping the animation

    requestId = requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    // animating/drawing code goes here
    animateIcons(requestId);

  }, 2000);
}


function animateIcons(requestId) {
  //get the visile element
  let curElem = $("#images div.sp:visible");

  //if next element exists
  let hasNext = curElem.next().length > 0;

  //if has next sibling
  if (hasNext) {
    //fade out the current element
    curElem.fadeOut(1000, function() {
      //fade in the next sibling
      curElem.next().fadeIn(1000);
    });
  } else {
    // //start animating from the start again
    let firstElem = $("#images div.sp:first-child");
    //fade out the current element
    curElem.fadeOut(1000, function() {
      //fade in the first element again
      firstElem.fadeIn(1000);
    });

    //or you can use the following alternatively
    //  to stop the animation 
    // stopAnimation(requestId);
  }

}

function stopAnimation(requestId) {
  // use the requestID to cancel the requestAnimationFrame call
  cancelAnimationFrame(requestId);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
  body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.9em;
  }
</style>
<div id="container" align="center">
  <div id="slider-wrapper">
    <div id="slider">
      <div class="backgoundImage">
        <div id="images"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have added `stopAnimation()` function with the code so if you are looking to stop the animation once it has animated all the images you can call it, I have passed the `requestId` to the function `animateIcons(requestId)` for the same purpose you can un-comment the code in the functions else part to use it, or you can remove it altogether if you plan not to use.